# Best Architecture to integrate a camera to a system

Tags: c++, embedded-systems

I'm trying to integrate a Camera to a more complex system in C++.
The camera I'm using has a low-level API so I'm thinking about using a more simple interface.
Basically what I'm planning to do is (in C++) :

- Camera will most probably run on a specified thread.
- Create an abstract `Camera` class interface with all my needs (`capture()`, `setExposure()` and so on...)
- Create a derived class `Mycam` implementing the various functions above as well as dealing with Bufferhandling etc..
- My camera needs to perfom various open-close pair (open the channel and then close it, allocated a buffer and free it...), therefore I was thinking using RAII Object for theses actions (for instance, create an object for each actions needed which will called the specified method during object initialization. Is it a good idea ?
- Should I use a singleton for my camera class ?

(for those wondering, I'm asking this question here after reading [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124867/where-should-i-ask-software-architecture-design-questions) but feel free to move it if it's off topic :)

- Also feel free to give me advice on things I should read/produce to help me see better !
  Thanks a lot !

[image]

Comment: Your question is very open-ended.  Would it be possible to narrow the scope of this question (and plan on follow up questions as needed) so it can be reasonably answered in a paragraph or three?

Comment: For example, what does the word "best" mean in this situation?  Easiest to code?  Easiest to understand? Easiest to extend to other hardware?

Comment: We can't say what's best without knowing the context of the system it will be used for.

Comment: There is no "best architecture for a camera". It depends on what you want the computer to *do*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what particular camera you are using. I have been using a variety of GigE vision cameras, and some other types, so some of these recommendations might not be applicable to your particular camera API.

> Camera will most probably run on a specified thread.

Yes, this will probably be the case.

> Create an abstract Camera class interface with all my needs (capture(), setExposure() and so on...)
> Create a derived class Mycam implementing the various functions above as well as dealing with Bufferhandling etc..

I would argue for separating the image-streaming parts of the camera from the configuration part of the camera. How to do the separation is more difficult, and might depend on your specific application.

I have made separate configuration classes for different camera models, with some common interfaces, and helpers to create the appropriate configuration object from the model name of the camera. But I'm not going to claim this is the best way to do it.

Using a (pure) abstract base class, or classes, is probably a good idea to allow for future alternative implementations.

> My camera needs to perfom various open-close pair (open the channel and then close it, allocated a buffer and free it...), therefore I was thinking using RAII Object for theses actions (for instance, create an object for each actions needed which will called the specified method during object initialization. Is it a good idea ?

Ideally I would recommend to avoid any per-frame allocations if possible. A workaround is to create a pool of buffers, and RAII might be suitable for for managing the buffer lifetime and returning it to the pool when done. The main alternative I know of is to require the image user to copy the image if he wants to use it on another thread than the camera-thread.

> Should I use a singleton for my camera class ?

Probably not. Why would you want to limit yourself to only ever having one single camera?

I would also keep in mind things like image formats. For a monochrome camera this is fairly simple, just a buffer of bytes or ushort. But for color cameras there are a whole bunch of ways to represent the colors. There might also be compression involved. So you might want some way to convert between formats, or to handle different formats in different ways.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.
I'm planning to use a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) for my frames management. and my images will be monochrome